# How to design a RESTful API with good performance

Tags: rest, api

When designing RESTful APIs, one of the rules is: "URI designates exactly one resource" , but in the real world we also like good performance and one thing to kill performance is the N+1 problem.

So how exactly are we supposed to avoid the N+1 problem without making more than one URI for the same resource `/api/foos/?page=1` or `/api/foo/1` where `/api/foos/` returns a list of foos in order to get decent performance.

Answer (score 3):

No one said you can't make a URI for `/api/foos/?page=1`. A container is not the same as the things it contains; a list of foos is a different resource from the individual foos.

Comment: But conceptually the same entity is at two different URIs now both in /api/foos/?page=1 and /api/foo/1 , but I see what you are saying and it makes sense if we see it like that.

Comment: But you can look at it as two different (not independent) resources - you just need to twist your nomenclature slightly so "resource" is not the same thing as "entity."

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen, no: `/api/foos/?page=1` is the first page of the container, it should be a list of elements. `/api/foos/1` is one element and still the 'real' URL of the resource.

Comment: There is no issue with a resource being at two URIs. For example you can have myweatherapp.com/today and myweatherapp.com/2015/feb/09 point to the same resource. A URI should only point to one resource, but a resource can have multiple URIs pointing to it.